# Adding my own custom sub page under the ACF Options menu

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I need to add my own custom page under the ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) "Options" page which I created with the correct code from the ACF site, which is working just fine.

So what I did was this:

```
function options_invoiceno(){ ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>testing sub page</h1>
        </div>
    <?php }

    function add_theme_menu_item() {

        add_submenu_page(
            "acf-options-invoice-design",
            "sub page",
            "sub page",
            "manage_options",
            "invoice-number",
            "options_invoiceno"
        );
    }
    add_action("admin_menu", "add_theme_menu_item");
```

which gives me the sub menu in the sidebar under "Options":

[image: sub menu item]

But when I click into the menu item I get a 404 Not Found page and the URL is incorrect: e.g. `http://example.com/wp-admin/acf-options-invoice-design-sub`

Am I missing something? is this even possible to add a sub menu under the existing ACF menu?

Any help or direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding a priority to your menu modifications, and see if that helps:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_theme_menu_item', 105 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I did use that way to add the other 2 sub pages. The problem is that I need to add a custom admin page (non ACF) under the Options menu as well.

Comment: hehe, it's already there.. (the 1st 5 lines of my code snippet)

Comment: OK, I also justy retried moving it into the add_theme_menu_item function, same thing happened. Then I tried removing the add_action and the "surrounding" function the action was calling, still doing the same thing

Comment: I must be blind.. ;) Updated again.

Comment: Ah, great, no problem. What was happening then was your code executing too early in comparison to ACF. With the priority set its happening after ACF is done doing its job.